# FXMl File is always null in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, path, fxml, scenebuilder

My file location is 100% correct, I checked it like a thousand times. Look at my folders and see the path. But somehow the path is always not found. I once tried to print it with the SOUT, it says null in the output. I have tried like 7-8 different solutions from Youtube and also created a full new project. But still not working.

[image]

FXML file path is not found.

Comment: Try to refactor `Main.fxml` into the same location as `hello-view.fxml`. I also feel like your main -> java should have package `com.example.tutprial`, but I don't see that. It just shows `FX`. I would suggest you start [here](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) and use one of the projects there as your starting project/template.

Comment: FXML files are resources, not Java source code. (They are not compiled.) In the standard layout, `.java` files in the `src/main/java` directory (and packages below that directory) will be *compiled* and the class files placed in the build. Files in the `src/main/resources` directory (and packages below that directory) will be *copied* to the build. If you check your actual runtime (build or target) folder, you will see that `Main.fxml` is not there, hence the error.

Comment: I have got my answer guys, thank you so much.
I have deleted the resource file like a dumb. Now when I take the path from resources, it's working.